# Create objects during run time?

Tags: javascript, json

In the code below, I have an array with two JSON objects, but what if I need 20 objects, do I have to write that 20 times in the array or is there a better way to create the 20 objects during runtime and add some random values to them while they are created?

I am aware of Javascript limitations compared to real OOP languages like Java or C# where I could create the objects from one class and just add them to a list.

```
var numbers = [
    {
    "x": 100,
    "y": 100,
    "visible": true,
    "value": 23
    },
    {
    "x": 150,
    "y": 100,
    "visible": true,
    "value": 19
    },
    ];
```

Comment: First: JavaScript _is_ a real OO language. Second: JS has a mechanism that lets you create objects from a constructor function. Third: what you have there is not JSON; [there's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: @nnnnnn I've decided to stop tilting at that language windmill. I think the "JSON object" folks have won the battle.

Comment: You can create objects in a loop, just like in any other language. It's not clear what problem you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: JavaScript *is* a real OO language. Second: JS has a mechanism that lets you create objects from a constructor function, or you could just use an object literal in a loop. Third: what you have there is not JSON; [there's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Having said that, here's one way to do what you're talking about:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var numbers = [];

for (var i=0; i < 20; i++) {
    numbers.push({
       "x": getRandomInt(0, 200),
       "y": getRandomInt(0, 200),
       "visible": true,
       "value": getRandomInt(0, 50)
    });
}
```

Or to use a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FWorking_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function):

```
function MyObject() {
   this.x = getRandomInt(0, 200);
   this.y = getRandomInt(0, 200);
   this.visible = true;
   this.value = getRandomInt(0, 50);
}

var numbers = [];

for (var i=0; i < 20; i++)
   numbers.push(new MyObject());
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example. Can I also call a function to get values inside the loop?

Comment: Yep. I've updated my answer to show a way to generate random integers between two numbers...

Comment: Actually this makes me wonder something. If i do : MyObject.prototype.whatever = Math.random(); Will random but ran once or at each instance creation ?

Comment: @Virus721 - it would run once, at the point where you include that line.

Comment: This is perhaps a stupid question, but what really happens if I don't use "this."?

Comment: If you don't use `this` within your constructor function then you can't add properties to the object that will be returned by the function. Note that there's nothing special about the function itself that makes it a constructor, the "magic" is when you call it with `new`. Did you read the MDN page I linked to about constructor functions? (Actually that page has a whole lot more about working with objects than just constructors.) JavaScript's `this` does _not_ work the same way as `this` in Java or C#, but for the example above you can think of it as being similar.

Comment: The Mozilla page is great! I have seen that page before, but forgotten it! I will study it more later! Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Now I'm confused! I thought "this" was the same in Javascript as in other languages like Java and C#!?

Comment: Nope. In Java and C# `this` always refers to the current instance of whatever class the method belongs to, right? In JavaScript the value of `this` depends on how a function/method is called - this isn't a bad thing, it's just something you need to be aware of. In the case of a function called with `new` as in my answer `this` will refer to the object being created like you would expect. MDN has [some stuff about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) that you could read.

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    numbers.push({
        x: Math.random(),
        y: Math.random(),
        visible: Math.round(Math.random() * 10) / 10) % 2 == 0,
        value: Math.random()
    });
}
```